# I didn't have much of a choice

Tags: phrase-usage

I am wondering if '**much of a**' in "*Sorry. I didn't have **much of a** choice*" is grammatical.

By any chance, is it a misuse of this:

> **not much of a…**
>   not a good…
>    - *He's not much of a tennis player.*
>   (Oxford Learner's Dictionary | much | [not much of a](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/much_1#much_1__73))

I see it's widely used. I've found [this page](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/367732) and also [this page](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/couldnt-you.773609/#post-16915296).

---

Allow me to summarize what I've learned here.

> **not much of a…** = not a good…

He's **not much of a** tennis player. = He *isn't a good* tennis player.

I **didn't** have **much of a** choice. = I *didn't* have *a good* choice. = <strike>That was unfavorable but the only choice for me.</strike>

About the same as "I didn't have much choice."

Indeed, I see in Google Ngram, [left](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20much%20of%20a%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Chave%20much%20of%20a%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhave%20much%20of%20a%20chance%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhave%20much%20of%20a%20choice%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhave%20much%20of%20a%20future%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhave%20much%20of%20a%20sense%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhave%20much%20of%20a%20problem%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhave%20much%20of%20a%20life%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhave%20much%20of%20a%20case%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhave%20much%20of%20a%20voice%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhave%20much%20of%20a%20social%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhave%20much%20of%20a%20time%3B%2Cc0) and [right](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not%20much%20of%20a%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cnot%20much%20of%20a%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnot%20much%20of%20a%20problem%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnot%20much%20of%20a%20place%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnot%20much%20of%20a%20success%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnot%20much%20of%20a%20hand%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnot%20much%20of%20a%20talker%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnot%20much%20of%20a%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnot%20much%20of%20a%20story%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnot%20much%20of%20a%20judge%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnot%20much%20of%20a%20job%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnot%20much%20of%20a%20one%3B%2Cc0), that it has many applications! Thank you! :)

[image] [image]

Comment: It's not a misuse—it is the _identical_ use. It may be the _didn't_ that is throwing you. _Didn't_ is a contraction of _did not._ The "not" in "not much of a" is included there.

Comment: Thank you for researching the phrase before asking here. The expression *much of a choice*, especially when used in the negative, as in *didn't have much of a choice* is idiomatic, natural, grammatical.

Comment: “Ruin my life to save a million others?It’s not much of a choice.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, yes, it's grammatical, and, no, it's not a misuse.

My instinct is that "didn't have much of a choice" implies more that **you were forced to make the choice** and less that the choice itself was bad. In retrospect, you might have made the worst choice possible, or the best choice possible, or somewhere in between. But it doesn't really matter how good the choice was because the point is that it wasn't actually a choice at all since there were't multiple things to (realistically) choose between.

Note that I added "(realistically)" because there's always a choice in life, but if your choices were to, say, wait until the traffic passes and end up late for a meeting or walk out into traffic and die, then you didn't have much of a choice but to be late for the meeting. So, yeah, technically you didn't have a *good* choice if "good" means getting you on time to the meeting in one piece, but that's not the point.

Oftentimes, your paraphrase of *"that was unfavorable but the only choice for me"* is the meaning people will be trying to convey by using the phrase, but my point is that that is not necessarily always the case. The emphasis is on the "only choice" bit, not the "unfavorable" bit.

Final note: I would not draw any distinction in meaning between *"I didn't have much of a choice"* and *"I didn't have much choice"*.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence

> Sorry. I didn't have **much of a** choice

has the meaning

> I didn't have **much** choice.
>   *I didn't have many choices*

where "**much**" signifies a figurative *quantity*.

In the same way,

> He's **not much of a** tennis player.
>   *He's not a very good tennis player*.

However, the opposite

> He's very **much** the tennis player.

has more the meaning that he's an *enthusiastic* tennis player, and may or may not also be good at it.  I would not say **much of a** is a misuse of **not much of a**.

It's all [*much of a muchness*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/much_of_a_muchness).

Comment: I find I was taking it something as "He's not much as a tennis player" and so it didn't make very good sense as "I didn't have much as a choice." In fact, I was having trouble why 'a' is used with 'much' when it's 'choice'. I think I can see what you mean by saying "It's all much of a muchness." Thank you. :)